# Spring and Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Can I use spring form tag library in conjunction with Ajax?
I'm not able to retrieve the form input parameters inside the controller. They are always **null**.

Actually there is a logic that the form is never submitted. But then I can only send strings to my controller and not an object as happens with a form submit that gets mapped to a Spring **commandBean**.

Form accepting the **commandBean**

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="clinicBean">
    Clinic Name: <form:input path="name" type="text" /><br/>
    Clinic Address: <form:input path="address" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Create Clinic" onclick="clinicAjax()"/>
</form:form>
```

Ajax function calling the **Spring controller**

```
function clinicAjax(){
    alert('Inside Clinic Ajax Method');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'clinicAjax',
        type: 'POST',
        success: alert('Ajax Successful')
    });
}
```

**Spring Controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="clinicAjax",method=RequestMethod.POST)


 public @ResponseBody String createClinic(@ModelAttribute("clinicBean") Clinic clinic){
        System.out.println("Ajax call successful");
        System.out.println(clinic);
        System.out.println(clinic.getName());
        System.out.println(clinic.getAddress());
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

It always gets **null** in the System.out.println() statements.

Comment: Adding some relevant code will help a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to use this configuration without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not serializing your form anywhere so it's not being sent to the server.

Change your javascript code to:

```
function clinicAjax(){
    alert('Inside Clinic Ajax Method');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'clinicAjax',
        data: yourFormElement.serialize(); /* i.e. $('#formId').serialize(); */
        type: 'POST',
        success: alert('Ajax Successful')
    });
}
```

substitute `yourFormElement` with jQuery object representing your form and it should work.